# uncaught type error javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to make a personality test.But i can get from questions.json only first questions,when i clicked the next questions button i am facing this error "Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

```
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA,chB,chC,totalCheck = 0;//değişkenler
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var ourData;
btn.addEventListener("click",function () {
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET','questions.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function () {
        ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        renderQuestion(ourData);

    }

    ourRequest.send();
})



var counters = [A=0,B=0,C=0];
function _(x){
return document.getElementById(x);//html dom
}
function renderQuestion(data){ //soru soran fonksiyon
test = _("test"); //dom ile test div ini seç
if(pos >= 4){
    for(var i = 0;i<choices.length;i++){test.innerHTML += "<h2>Sonuç : "+data[i].soru+" dan "+ counters[i] +" kadar işaretledin</h2>";}// test divine sonucu yazdır
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed"; // "test_status" başlığına test bitti yazdır
    pos = 0; // pos tekrar 0 yap
    correct = 0; // dogru sayısını tekrar 0 yap;
    return false; //false döndür
}


_("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+"of"+data.length; // "test_status başlığına hangi soruda olduğunu yazdır
question = data[pos].soru; // questions listesinden 0. yani soru kısmını question değişkenine ata
chA = data[pos].siklar1; // 1.cevap
chB = data[pos].siklar2; // 2.cevap
chC = data[pos].siklar3; // 3.cevap
test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>"; //soruyu yazdır
test.innerHTML += "<input type='checkbox' name='choices' value='A'>"+chA+"<br>"; //1.cevabı yazdır
test.innerHTML += "<input type='checkbox' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>"; //2.cevabı yazdır
test.innerHTML += "<input type='checkbox' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>"; //3.cevabı yazdır
test.innerHTML += "<button class='button' onclick='checkAnswer()'> NEXT QUESTİONS >> </button>"    //cevabı kontrol et fonksiyonunu cağır
}
function checkAnswer(){
choices = document.getElementsByName("choices"); // seçenekler domunu seç
if(choices[0].checked){
    if(choices[1].checked || choices[2].checked){
        findChecked(choices);
    }
    else{
        counters[0]+=2;
    }
}
else if(choices[1].checked){
    if(choices[0].checked || choices[2].checked){
        findChecked(choices);
    }
    else{
        counters[1]+=2;
    }
}
else if(choices[2].checked){
    if(choices[0].checked || choices[1].checked){
        counters[2]++;
    }
    else{
        counters[2]+=2;
    }
}
pos++; // pozisyonu 1 arttır
renderQuestion(); //render questionsu tekrar çağır
}
function findChecked(answers) {
for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    if (answers[i].checked == true) {
        counters[i]++;
        totalCheck++;
    }
}
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

Comment: Use the console to see where and what causes the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're calling `renderQuestion` without any parameter. So `data.length` might be throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which line is throwing the error for sure (hint: please provide the line number of the error as well), at a guess I'd say it's this line you're getting the error on

`_("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+"of"+data.length;`

So make sure `data` has a `length` attribute